# Delete and perform a fresh install of WordPress

Tags: posts, installation, backup, uninstallation

I have a blog page on my site, and after several people tried to help fix a problem it has gotten to the point that I get a lot of errors.

I am looking to delete my blog I reinstall it again, hopefully this will fix all of the issues.

If I save all the posts from my blog, delete the blog, and reinstall it again - can I add those posts back to my blog? Will it keep all of the original dates? Or will it show all of the dates based on the import date?

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress importer / exporter should work for this task (maintaining post dates and comments), but it's better to test it before deleting the online blog.

My advice is to create first a fresh install in a folder (so you'll can temporary reach your new installation at www.yoursite/folder/ ) and test if everything works fine importing post to the new location. Just then you can delete the old blog and move your index.php to the root (for detailed explanation on how handle wordpress installation in a folder refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory ).

This way you can test first the migration and then substitute the old blog with the new one when everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

> *If I save all the posts from my blog, delete the blog, and reinstall it again - can I add those posts back to my blog?*

Yes you can. This can be easily done by going to *Tools > Export* in the admin Dashboard to save all of your posts into a file. Then, once you reinstall your new WordPress site, you can go to *Tools > Import* and upload the exported file with all of your old posts.

Checkout this helpful article for more details: [How To Import Posts & Pages From One WordPress Website To Another](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/import-export-wordpress-website)

> *Will it keep all of the original dates?*

Yes.

> *Or will it show all of the dates based on the import date?*

No, it will show the original post dates.